# Date format handling while reading from Excel in PHP

Tags: php, excel, datetime

I am reading from Excel and I am not sure what date format will be in the Excel file. I need it in the specific format of "Y-m-d H:i:s".

I have an example which I got from Excel:

17/03/2018 00:00  and  3/1/2018 0:37

```
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('17/03/2018 00:00'));   
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('3/1/2018 0:37'));
```

The result I got is:

first one :  1970-01-01 05:30:00
second one : 2018-03-01 00:37:00
in which the first is wrong and the second is correct. I know that it is not correctly reading the month but how can I handle this?

Can anyone help me with handling any format which comes from Excel?

Comment: It does not follow the indian standards. The correct format should be: `strtotime('03/17/2018 00:00')`. Or use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. Also note that you can not convert *any format* to a `date`. format of the date should be already known. You can definitely use `strtotime` to convert almost every type of string to date but not *any format*

Comment: Hi Aniket, i don't have control over csv file.

Comment: I understand your concern but date written by human in any format is ambiguous. For eg: `01-02-03`, will you interpret as *1st Feb 2003* or *2nd Jan 2003* or *3rd Jan 2002*? It is not possible to come to a conclusion. So the best you can do is try to convert string to timestamp using `strtotime` and if it fails to return a timestamp then let human handle it.

Comment: If you get 02/01/2018 is it 1st of Feb or 2nd of Jan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('/','-',"17/3/2018 00:00"))); 

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('/','-','3/1/2018 0:37')));
```

Comment: Note: this approach only solves the given test cases and will fail to convert *any format* as required in OP.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I know i have given the solution of first one : 1970-01-01 05:30:00 and i am assuming Indian date format d/m/yyyy

Comment: Even if we consider that you gave solution for only indian date format, it is so unnecessary to first `str_replace` and then convert it to ts. I am sure parsing the string using `DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i", "17/3/2018 00:00")->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");` must be way faster than doing this.